# Setting expires via htaccess on combine script

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using a script to combine my css and js files together, wich results in an url like this:

http://gportdev.nl/framework/wp-content/themes/gport_framework/public/css/combine.php?type=css&files=base/reset.css,theme/layout.css,theme/typography.css,forms/uniform.default.css,video/video-js.css,slider/nivo-slider.css,slider/themes/default/default.css

I am using the following code to set expires and ET's, but I'm wondering how i can make sure that the above url also gets expires.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(swf|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|gif|combine.php)(\.gz)?$">

Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

</FilesMatch>
```

Is there any way to achieve this? simply adding combine.php doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you are doing this the wrong way.  You should use the PHP "header()" function within `combine.php` to do this, e.g.

```
$expiresOffset = ...; //some offset that you've calculated like 31*24*3600;
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");  // Handle proxies
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $expiresOffset) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=" . $expiresOffset);
```

but remember to invoke any headers before you emit the compressed output.